# Sending and Receiving JSON data from a Servlet

Tags: java, json, web-services, servlets

How can I send JSON data to my Servlet's `doPost()` method and receive it back? I have a web service which produces and consumes JSON.

Answer (score 3):

Use the HttpServletRequest and  HttpServletResponse arguments that are passed to your doPost method in a servlet

```
public class ExampServlet extends HttpServlet {
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    // to accept the json data

    String jsonData = request.getParameter("json");  

    // to send out the json data

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(jsonData) ; 
    out.close() /
   }
```

Comment: Could you share an example please?